# Java sorting an ArrayList of objects by 3 fields with priorities, getting unexpected results

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have a class Order (I cut out setters and getters for smaller size).

```
class Order implements Comparable<Order>{
    private int number;
    private int price;
    private int quantity;
    private boolean isMarketOrder;
    private boolean isBuyOrder;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Order o) {
        int value1 = Boolean.compare(this.isMarketOrder(), o.isMarketOrder());
        if (value1 != 0){
            return value1;
        }
        int value2 = Integer.compare(this.getPrice(),(o.getPrice()));
        if (value2 != 0) {
            return value2;
        }
        int value3 =  Integer.compare(this.getNumber(),(o.getNumber()));
        return value3;
    }
}
```

And I have a list of orders:

```
public static ArrayList<Order> buyOrders = new ArrayList<Order>();
```

I do

```
Collections.sort(buyOrders);
```

**What rules I want to use when sorting:**

1. Orders with isMarketOrder == true ALWAYS come first
2. Orders with same isMarketOrder value are sorted by price, higher first
3. Orders with same isMarketOrder and price are sorted by "number", smaller first.

What actually happens is higher price items come first and `isMarketOrder == true` items come last.

Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `true` is greater than `false`, so the ordering you are using sorts `isMarketOrder==false` to go before `isMarkerOrder==true`. If you have:

```
int value1 = Boolean.compare(this.isMarketOrder(), o.isMarketOrder());
if (value1 != 0){
    return -value1;
}
```

you will get the opposite effect.

Comment: Silly me, I thought it was reverse. Thanks, solved my problem!